# What does the this characters/operator mean in javascript/jquery selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, operator-keyword

If there's a duplicate please pardon me. It's just difficult for me to identify what this js operator mean.

```
**^=**
```

Sample code.

```
    var containerObj = $("#containerList").closest("[id^=Selection-list]");
```

I am talking specifically with this part of the code: `[id^=Selection-list]`

Comment: A little reading might help: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ and http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^=` this means [attribute value starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Your selector

`.closest("[id^=Selection-list]");`

would select the parent element of `$('#containerList')` has id start with `Selection-list`

Comment: *"...would select the parent element of..."* It checks the element itself first, before looking at the parent. Of course, in this particular case, we know that an element with the `id` `"containerList"` doesn't match the selector `"[id^=Selection-list]"`, but still...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah that's completely right, and that's the major difference between the `.closest()` and `.parents()`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's the starting with selector.

[Check here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

There's other attributes selectors too check it [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

It means that select where attribute id starts with 'Selection-list', you should check this [link](http://www.xinotes.net/notes/note/958/)
to get knowledge about special characters in JQuery.